# Word to PDF and PDF to Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, documents

When we convert Word to PDF files we get good result – like any kind of alignment and pictures will be kept.

But when we convert a PDF to word, most of the time we get very ugly results, especially when it comes to tables, boxes and alignment.

Why is that?

Comment: that will happen with free tools out there.. Still, i'll try to find a good one for you.

Answer (score 4):

The document structure of PDF and Microsoft Word are totally different. Everything in PDF is fixed, when you create PDF, all the elements in Word doc will be located in a certain place in PDF document, that's why PDF files can keep the original look in different operation system, screen size, etc. Microsoft Word can save as PDF.

While you convert PDF to Word, Word doc is reflowable so it's hard to locate elements in exact location, so the original format may lost. Even the Acrobat can't convert PDF to Word 100% accurately. Output quality depends on the developer's algorithm. [Solid Document](http://www.soliddocuments.com/) works great on Windows, while NitroPDF provide online converter pdftoword.com, [Cycle PDF Converter for Mac](http://www.cycledocument.com/pdf-converter-mac.html) is great, and if you want to convert scanned PDF to editable Word doc, ABBYY's OCR can help.

Answer (score -2):

You can purchase an advanced version of Adobe PDF that will allow you to select the PDF file you're interested in and then get Adobe PDF to convert it to Word for you.  The conversions come over about 95% correct.

There are also several software programs online that you can use for a trial period (usually 7 days) to convert PDF to Word files.  Just Google "convert PDF to Word" and look for those that allow trial periods.

Comment: While your recommendation can be valid,  it doesn't answer the question "why"?